# Cannot add Push Notifications to Debug in Xcode 13

Tags: xcode, push-notification

I get the following error in the console when running the app:

`[Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM012002] Error in application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: no valid “aps-environment” entitlement string found for application`

In Capabilities I have added "Push Notifications" but it only seems to be added to the Release build. In "All" it says `Push Notifications (Release)` If I go to the Debug tab and add Capabilities, I can see Push Notifications; however, if I double click it or drag it in, nothing happens. It does not add nor show and there is no error thrown.

I presume the error I receive in the console is due to the missing capability for debug which I cannot seem to add unlike for release. Remote notifications are also checked in the "Background Modes" section.

Answer (score 0):

i had also this problem.
I HAVE SOME WORK AROUND FOR THIS.. NOT SURE HOW ITS WORK IN PRODACTION.
what i did is copy the entitlements file and change is name from
testRelease.entitlements
to
test.entitlements

test is the name of app

Answer (score 0):

Opening up Xcode, and go to the
**Project Properties > Build Settings > Code Signing Entitlements >** Ensure the name of the entitlement file should be the same for *'Both Debug and Release Configuration'.*
For Example... **$(SRCROOT)/$(PRODUCT_NAME)/$(PRODUCT_NAME).entitlements**
PRODUCT_NAME is your target name.